# URL rewriting using .htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is a link to a website I am making (I am very new to this) - http://www.inquivesta.iiserkol.ac.in. I am using .htaccess to try and rewrite the URLs for some of the pages. One of them is the about us page whose actual link is - www.inquivesta.iiserkol.ac.in/Home/index.php and I want it to look like www.inquivesta.iiserkol.ac.in/about/

So I wrote this in the .htaccess file :-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about/?$   /Home/index.php [NC,L]
```

This doesn't seem to work. Whenever people open this page, I don't want it to display the filename. But the filename is stil being displayed. And if I try to open http://www.inquivesta.iiserkol.ac.in/about/ then it redirects to www.inquivesta.iiserkol.ac.in/Home/index.html

Comment: Yes, that's what is happening

Comment: When I entered `http://www.inquivesta.iiserkol.ac.in/about/` in browser, it stayed at same URL